# Calling firmware entry point in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

I've written a bootloader for my embedded project, and it works in debug, and also in debug with optimizations on (`-Os`). However, entering the main firmware in release mode (`-Os`, `NDEBUG` etc) fails, the call ends up with a hard fault. To as far as I can trust my debugger with all optimizations on, it appears that the jump to the entry point instead ends up jumping to `0x00000000`. Interestingly, if I just add a check that the entry point is not zero, everything works, so this is a Heisenbug.

Compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc.

The main firmware entry point is

```
//Defined by the linker scripts
//Constants
extern uint32_t __MAIN_APP_BEGIN;

using jump_ptr_t = void (*)(uint32_t);

...snip...

void Image::run_image(uint32_t param) const {

    //Access the main app vector table
    const uint32_t *main_vectors = &__MAIN_APP_BEGIN;

    //First entry is the initial stack pointer
    const auto stack_init = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(main_vectors[0]);
    //mEntryPoint, a uint32_t has been read earlier from the firmware image header,
    //checked to make sense (lies within the
    //firmware image region etc)
    const auto entry_point = reinterpret_cast<jump_ptr_t>(mEntryPoint);

    //Sanity check (left out in release)
    assert(is_valid() && entry_point != nullptr && stack_init != 0);

    //If I uncomment the following line, this works
    /*if (mEntryPoint == 0)
        return;*/

    //Set the stack pointer for the process we are going to
    //NOTE: OUR OWN STACK IS NOW CORRUPT
    //so we MUST NOT RETURN!
    Hardware::set_MSP(stack_init);

    entry_point(param);

    //No returning, stack is broken
    assert(false);
}
```

Now, I suppose that using the pointer acquired via `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behaviour, and so the optimizer doesn't think it necessary to actually load the value from memory etc. Actually, I just realized that I'm probably also relying on the address having been loaded to a register already, since I destroy the local stack on the line just before the jump...

The question: how do I call my firmware without invoking undefined behaviour in C++? Or does it inevitably require inline assembler?

**Update:**

Here's the last few lines of disassembly without the check, just before the jump:

```
msr     MSP, r3
ldr     r0, [r6, #0]
ldr     r3, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
blx     r3
```

and here with the check (i.e. the case that works):

```
ldr     r3, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
ldr     r2, [r5, #0]
msr     MSP, r2
cmp     r3, #0
beq.n   0x800051c <_start()+760>
ldr     r0, [r6, #0]
blx     r3
```

So it really appears that even with the check, it works at best by dumb luck, due to the different order of stack loads vs. setting the stack pointer.

Comment: I haven't done much in that field with c++, but isn't that a case for which `volatile` is used?

Comment: If I try to make `using jump_ptr_t = void (* volatile)(uint32_t)` I get `type qualifiers ignored on cast result type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]`. Writing `volatile const auto entry_point = reinterpret...` does not help. I.e. it's not clear what should I make volatile here?

Comment: Assuming that `mEntryPoint` is an integral value or a pointer to `void`, you are kneedeep in UB land at the call `entry_point(param)`. I do not think you can get out of that with plain C++. You need help from the compiler (possibly via inline assembly) or a library function which give you the guarantees that exceed C++'s capabilities.

Comment: Could you check the generated assembly? Is it possible that the compiler simply delayed the load of entry_point until `entry_point(param)` which is after you destroyed the stack without the compiler knowing about it. If so, maybe something like a memory fence can help you.

Comment: @MicroVirus you're actually right, when I have the check `mEntryPoint  == 0` it gets loaded from the stack before changing the stack pointer, whereas when the check isn't there it's just after that. So it's really dumb luck that it works even with the check.

Comment: @MicroVirus See edit, I added the disassembly. Also, simply not setting the stack pointer makes this work, since the main firmware then just builds its stack on top of (or rather, below) the bootloader stack (which is obviously suboptimal).

Comment: I think you confused the two assembler snippets, the second one is the one that does not contain the check, and which loads the target address from the stack `[sp, #40]` after updating the `MSP`.

Comment: Which means that your assumption is correct: The optimizer does not know that `set_MSP()` changes the meaning of the stack. The compiler has every right to place any variable (even when declared as `register`) on the stack, and if you decide to manipulate the stack, the compiler has every right to assume you know what you are doing, and load local variables from the manipulated stack.

Comment: As such, the only way to fix this reliably is to perform the `MSR` move and the subsequent jump in an inline assembler snippet.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica you're right, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica and yes, I think you're also correct that this has to be done in assembler.